# "www" CNAME not working for S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a website comprised of a few static pages hosted on an AWS S3 bucket. I added an A record that maps `mysite.com` to the bucket's address (via an alias). I also want users to be able to access my site via `www.mysite.com`, but when I add a CNAME mapping `www.mysite.com.` to `mysite.com` it does not work. What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain name has to match the bucket name. The fix is to create a second bucket with `www.` in the name, point your `www` CNAME to that, and configure that bucket to redirect to the other bucket that contains your website.

Answer (score 0):

The `www.mysite.com` should be an A record pointing to a separate S3 bucket. If you want users to always go to your `www` site then you'll put your site files in the `www` bucket and setup your top-level domain bucket to redirect to `www.mysite.com`.